# How Action is invoking method which is having a parameter

Tags: c#, delegates

I am trying to learn `Action` delegate and lambda in C#.
So far I came to know that `Action` delegate encapsulates a method that does not have any parameter and returns `void`.

If we want to encapsulate a method having a parameter then we should use `Action<T>`. In the code which I am sharing, the method is having `int` parameter. And I am using `Action` delegate instead of `Action<T>`. Still I am able to invoke the method.

I am not able to understand this. Could anyone please explain the reason?

```
public static void Fourth(Action action)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Fourth invoked");
    action();
}
public static void Third(int x)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Third invoked");
    int result;
    result = 3 + x;
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
Action a2 = () => Third(50);
Fourth(a2);
```

Answer (score 1):

This line `Action a2 = () => Third(50);` creates a new parameter less method, which executes the `Third()` method.

If you want to assign the Third method to a2. You should write `Action<int> a2 = Third;`. Which will result in calling `a2(50);`

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to get confused here.

`a2` is not *encapsulating* the method `Third`. It uses an anonymous method declared via your *lambda*

```
() => Third(50);
```

This is converted by the compiler to a method in your class like that:

```
private static void SomeSpecialName() // so special that the name can't be used in C#, hence anonymous
{
    Third(50);
}
```

and it is that `SomeSpecialName()` (having *no* arguments) method that `a2` now refers to.